# deploy a Jekyll site with the use of a

Tags: html, git, github, jekyll

This is the first time that I am going to use Jekyll to build a static site. I would like to use a dozen plugins that are not white listed for deploying on Github.  My question is :  is it possible to deploy a such site with a dozen plugins (not white listed) on github ? 
Browsing on internet, I found the following assertions :
1) We can't run user plugins on GitHub Pages due to security restrictions. That' what the documentation says
2) You are free to generate your site locally and push the resulting HTML to a Git repo, however : what does that means ? First when you generate the site locally, it ends with a group of HTML files and that group of html files, are they enough to run the site autonomously (for example must you include the css files in html pages ) ? Furthermore when you push the resulting HTML to a Git repo, is it enough to deploy it on a production environment (on GITHUB for example) ? and how you do that ?
3) on this link (https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-plugins-with-github-pages/) I found the following explaination : Adding Jekyll plugins to a GitHub Pages site

You can further customize your GitHub Pages site by adding Jekyll plugins. (do they talk about all plugins ?)

GitHub Pages officially supports the Jekyll plugins found in the GitHub Pages gem. For the exact versions of the Jekyll plugins that GitHub Pages supports, see this list of GitHub Pages dependencies. Other plugins are not supported, so the only way to incorporate them in your site is to generate your site locally and then push your site's static files to your GitHub Pages site.
So as they say, it is possible , generating your site locally and then pushing your site's static files to your GitHub Pages site. Is there a detailled procedure example somewhere ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use Jekyll with any plugins  and host in Github pages you have two options

## first alternative

Build your site locally and then push the resulting site at `_site` to Github.

Then push the built site's static files to your pages publishing branch (gh-pages or master depending on your site type).

> GitHub Pages supports any HTML or static files you push to it so you
>   can use any static site generator to build your site. You can even
>   just push raw HTML files to GitHub Pages and it will build your site.
>   You can also customize your own build process locally or on another
>   server.

## second alternative

Use a CI service like Travis, so when you push your Jekyll files to Github, it automatically builds your site and deploy it to your publishing branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marcanuy

Comment: Second question Marcanuy, which alternative is best, considering the ease of use, the possibilities to use other tools or other advantages that I don't see for the moment

Comment: That depends on many factors and probably beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: Another question : I think I am going to use the first alternative. Does it mean that I am going to create my Jekyll site locally   add a GIT repository to track history change,  generate the final html files, and when the site is finished push all the files to GITHUB Pages in whatever tree (I mean a tree to sort each different type of files (html, css, images, videos, etc...)) configuration ?